# SQL query not working with function DateAdd

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select DATEADD(day,-1,cast(getdate() as date)) as yesterday 
from dual;
```

I am using this query for subtracting one day from date but this is showing invalid identifier in my sql server. Can you pls suggest some alternative.

Comment: Query works for me.  Does 'dual' exist?

Comment: make sure you've got the right schema. It's not a bad habit to get into where you always explicitly name your table schemas. e.g. 

`select DATEADD(day,-1,cast(getdate() as date)) as yesterday from dbo.dual;`

Comment: Note that `GETDATE()` returns the server's local date, which will likely _not_ be the same as your user's date. You should never store local dates+times in a database: only store UTC values (or UTC-based values, like `datetimeoffset`) _unless you absolutely know what you are doing_.

Comment: i am using oracle

Comment: then why do you tag your question for sql server in stead of oracle ?

Answer (score 3):

> but this is showing invalid identifier in my sql server.

The *invalid identifier* error is because the virtual-table `DUAL` does not exist in MS SQL Server.

The `DUAL` virtual-table is a feature of Oracle, MySQL 8+, and MariaDB.

In SQL Server (T-SQL) the idiomatic way to return a scalar in a single-row, single-column table is to either:

- Use `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause - this is allowed in T-SQL, just be sure to use a semicolon at the end:

  ```
  SELECT
      DATEADD( day, -1, CAST( GETDATE() AS date) ) AS yesterday;
  ```
- Use the `VALUES()` [table constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

  ```
  SELECT
      t.yesterday
  FROM
      (
          VALUES
              ( DATEADD( day, -1, CAST( GETDATE() AS date) ) )
      ) AS t( yesterday )
  ```

  - Note that when a `VALUES()` table-constructor is used as an immediate child of a `FROM` clause the entire expression needs to be wrapped in parentheses, which sets it apart from the `VALUES()` syntax seen in `INSERT` and `MERGE` statements.
- Use a T-SQL `@variable`:

  ```
  DECLARE @yesterday date = DATEADD( day, -1, CAST( GETDATE() AS date) );
  SELECT @yesterday AS yesterday;
  ```

---

Comment: The second option results in `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'`

Comment: In case you want more columns, here is a simple example `select t.* from  ( values (1, 'one'), (2, 'two') ) t(id, name)`

Comment: I am using oracle

Comment: @AyushmaanAgrawal That is not what you said in your question ! You put sql server there